# Unclose a nested dictionary to simple dictionary without using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Below is a dictionary which has keys as string and value as either a dictionary or integer.

```
sample = {"A": 1, "B1": {"BB1": {"B" : 2}}, "C1": {"C" : 3} }
```

I want to print the key and value wherever the value is an integer.
so, the output should be.

```
{"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}
```

Note: I need to know if this can be solved without recursion.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks, *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Comment: Deep recursion will lead to stack-overflow in case of deeply nested dictionaries. I solved this question by recursion in an interview but the interviewer was not happy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse your dictionary. Though this will use `recursion`.

```
def traverse(dictEx):
    for k, v in dictEx.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            traverse(v)
        elif type(v) == int:
            print({k:v})
sample = {"A": 1, "B1": {"BB1": {"B" : 2}}, "C1": {"C" : 3}}
traverse(sample)
```

Here is another solution without recursion.

```
def traverse(dictEx):
        it = list(dictEx.items())
        while it:
            k, v = it.pop()
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                it.extend(v.items())
            elif type(v) == int:
                print({k:v})
sample = {"A": 1, "B1": {"BB1": {"B" : 2}}, "C1": {"C" : 3}}
traverse(sample)
```

**outputs**

```
{'A': 1}
{'B': 2}
{'C': 3}
```

Comment: I solved this way only. But this solution has a problem of stack-overflow. I can't think of any other approach to solve this without recursion. Wondering what will be the approach to solve it without recursion.

Comment: i've given an example. please take a look at my answer once more.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing the values at every level, you can use a generator with a breadth-first search to build an output dictionary:

```
sample = {"A": 1, "B1": {"BB1": {"B" : 2}}, "C1": {"C" : 3} }
def get_leaves(d):
   q = [d]
   while q:
      for a, b in q.pop(0).items():
         if not isinstance(b, dict):
            yield (a, b)
         else:
             q.append(b)

r = dict(get_leaves(sample))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}
```